# Whitelist Multiple IP Addresses with ModSecurity

Tags: apache, mod-security2

I have 2 IP addresses that I need to whitelist with ModSecurity.
So far I can only get it to whitelist 1 IP at a time.

I've tried:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 35.178.146.26,81.138.11.237" phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off
```

and

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 35.178.146.26" phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off 
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 81.138.11.237" phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off
```

and also

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 35.178.146.26"\
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 81.138.11.237"\
phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off
```

But none of these Whitelist both IP addresses and one will still show up in the Audit log.

Once I've added these rules and try to restart Apache I get the error which references the second rule:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: I believe your first one should work (maybe you need to add quotes to the last part. I have the following working rule (I changed the IPs) `SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3/24" "phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=off,id:1"`

Answer (score -1):

You need to space-separate them. Also: There is ipMatchFromFile that lets you list them one-per-line.